# NSNumberFormatter with significant digits formats 0.0 incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumberformatter

I've got an NSNumberFormatter set up to format using significant digits, so it should only show as many decimal digits as are necessary to correctly display the value.

When it is used to format `7.0` it works exactly as expected and produces `@"7"`, but when it is used to format `0.0` the formatter produces `@"0.0"` instead of `@"0"` as would be expected.

```
NSNumberFormatter *doubleValF = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[doubleValF setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[doubleValF setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];

doubleValF.maximumFractionDigits = 9;
doubleValF.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
doubleValF.minimumSignificantDigits = 0;
doubleValF.maximumSignificantDigits = 30;
[doubleValF setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];

double value1 = 0.0;
NSString *value1String = [doubleValF stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value1]];

double value2 = 7.0;
NSString *value2String = [doubleValF stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value2]];

NSLog(@"value1=%@", value1String);
NSLog(@"value2=%@", value2String);
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
2012-12-15 15:57:03.425 StackOverflowTests[41701:11303] value1=0.0
2012-12-15 15:57:03.426 StackOverflowTests[41701:11303] value2=7
```

Answer (score 1):

Following David's LaMacchia's post, just check for a zero value and set the sig fig mode:

```
if(fabs(value) < 1e-6) {
    self.numberLabelFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = NO;
}
else {
    self.numberLabelFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
}
self.numberLabel.text = [self.numberLabelFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]];
```

This may not be the *correct* method, but it works for me.

Comment: Whenever you see a floating point value and == together, you should have a siren go off in your head, because you should not trust that the variable is EXACTLY 0.0 through the entire value.

Comment: Sure. But I don't need much accuracy and it's working fine. In this case, I'm not worried.

Comment: It's not the accuracy of the number itself when it comes to calculations, I'm referring to whether or not the if() statement will evaluate to true. You could have a number which 0.00000001 which you think should be 0, but it will evaluate to false when compared to 0.0 and your else clause will fire instead of if.

Comment: Your code will most likely work every time you test it, but it's possible for it to fail arbitrarily. You should consider changing your if() statement to something like `if (fabs(value) < 1e-6)` which will evaluate to true as long as value is between -0.000001 and 0.000001.

Comment: @KennyWyland Good advice. The exact value to test against is FLT_EPSILON for a float.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to your having set `usesSignificantDigits` to `YES`.  I believe the trailing digit, in `0.0`, is considered significant.

There's a good discussion of a related issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110633/1435955

Comment: I read the linked article and I don't believe it addresses my specific problem, which is that the .0 is included only if the value is 0. In the case of 7.0, it is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set zeroSymbol property of number formatter to @"0".

```
doubleValF.zeroSymbol = @"0";
```