# No zero before decimal point

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I have a function that converts float numbers to string:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSString *finalNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sendNumber]];
return finalNumber;
```

After a simple divide operation 1/2 I get the result as `.5` but I was hoping to get `0.5`.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the formatting for significant digits. Check out this thread for some good info: [What describes NSNumberFormatter -maximumSignificantDigits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322348/what-describes-nsnumberformatter-maximumsignificantdigits/13110633#13110633)

Answer (score 24):

Just use

```
[formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
```

That gives at least one digit before decimal point.

Comment: YES! Exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot! Just to update for Swift 5: `let format = NumberFormatter() 
format.minimumIntegerDigits = 1 `