# NSNumberFormatter: Displaying zero as last digit starting from a string like 25.0

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nsformatter

I have a string that represents a float, for example `2400.0`. I want to format it as digit (`2,400.0`) and I need to keep the zero after the digit symbol.

```
NSString* theString = @"2400.0"; 

// I convert the string to a float 
float f = [theString floatValue]; 
// here I lose the digit information :( and it ends up with 2400 instead of 2400.0

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(f)];
```

The `NSLog` of `result` is `2,400` while I need `2,400.0`

How can I obtain the right string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to set the [`minimumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits%3a) to 1 (and your `maximumFractionDigits` as well in this case).

You also probably don't want to use significant digits. The following code yields the desired output:

```
NSString *theString = @"2400.0";

float f = [theString floatValue];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(f)]);
```

Comment: the problem is that during the first conversion from string to float I lose the ".0" information. I've already tried to set `minimumFractionDigits`. Btw I add it to the my code example to be more precise.

Comment: I don't understand how you can lose the `.0` (a different fraction I can understand, but `.0`?) Anyway, you'll need two number formatters: one for input and another one for output.

Comment: Oh, and since you set `setUsesSignificantDigits:YES` you might want to set the [`minimumSignificantDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumSignificantDigits:) as well (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322348/what-describes-nsnumberformatter-maximumsignificantdigits)) or turn them off.

Comment: What do you mean with 2 number formatters? how I use the Input one?

Comment: If you try to take the code that I wrote... you get exactly the string `2,400` but I want to obtain `2,400.0`

Comment: I thought you're also parsing the string with the number formatter, missed the `[theString floatValue]` part. I've edited my answer with sample code that yields your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Te below solves the issue

```
NSString *formatString = @"0,000.0";
[formatter setPositiveFormat:formatString];
```

The number of 0's after decimal will be used for formatting. It works for negative numbers also.

you should dynamically change the format string based on number of digits of the float value before and after decimal point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to keep the locale information. This is not a solution. Many countries use a different format like `@"0.000,0"`

Comment: Agree, it is not a generic solution. However it serves the question asked "need a format for 0,000.0" for generic solution we need to set locale to formatter.

Answer (score 0):

easy,

then you go to display it just do this:

```
myLabel.text = @"%0.1f", f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `minimumFractionDigits` in addition to `maximumFractionDigits`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;

XCTAssert([[formatter stringFromNumber:@(2400.0)] isEqualToString:@"2400.0"]);
XCTAssert([[formatter stringFromNumber:@(2400.1)] isEqualToString:@"2400.1"]);
```