# NSNumberFormatter stringFromNumber returning 1,000,000,000 for input 999999999

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to convert number 999999999 to string using NSNumberFormatter, I am getting wrong value. It returns 1,000,000,000 instead of 999,999,999.

Here is the code that I use.

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];

numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"999999999" ]];
NSLog(@"Currency String %@",numberAsString);
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a decimal number, pass it through a formatter (that's configured as a currency formatter??), and pass it back into a string?

Comment: offtopic: use dot notation for properties as suggested in many objc styleguide's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified to use significant digits, but didn't say how many to use. For example, if you add the following, you get the result you were expecting:

```
[numberFormatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:9];
```

So, if you're going to use significant digits, specify how many you want to use. Or don't use significant digits at all.

Comment: @matthias , Rob  setting significant digits solved my issue. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

You enabled `usesSignificantDigits`. Default value for `maximumSignificantDigits` is 6. Which means every number with more than 6 significant digits will be rounded to have less than 6 significant digits.

`999 999 999` has 9 significant digits. So it will be rounded to `1 000 000 000`

You probably don't want to set `usesSignificantDigits` at all.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110633/457406) is a good explanation what significant digits do with NSNumberFormatter.